# ES6 style import statement not working in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, webstorm, commonjs

I'm trying to do simple import/export in TypeScript as follows:

**animals.ts**

```
export const someVar=5;
```

**main.ts**

```
import {someVar} from './animals';
```

But compiler is saying:

[image: Compilation errors]

Below are my typescript compiler options:

```
-t ES6 -m commonjs
```

I've tried amd in module options as well but with no luck. RequireJs seems to be working fine though.

My TypeScript version is 2.2.2 and using WebStorm IDE.

What am I missing here? Please bear with me as I am new to this.

**Edit**

`tsc main.ts` compiles perfectly fine. But WebStorm still whining about compilation errors.

Comment: What's your tsconfig.json look like? How do you turn the typescript sources into js ones? Via regular tsc? Do you use webpack or gulp or babel etc?

Comment: I'm using tsc inbuit into webstorm without tsconfig.json. But giving below compiler options from settings view
-t ES6 -m commonjs

Comment: For all intents and purposes this is very basic stuff which should work. I think there's something wrong with the webstorm js config. You should try running `tsc` outside it, from a command line, and check to see it works.

Comment: @HoriaComan you are so right, tsc main.ts does compile correctly without errors. Somethings just wrong with Webstorm I guess.

Comment: Did you set the configuration "Languages & Frameworks" => JavaScript to ECMAScript 6?

Comment: @str I tried but with no effect.

Comment: I upgraded the webstorm to latest version and it worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.
I was using old webstorm 10 that was using typescript compiler version 1.4. I upgraded the webstorm to 2017.1 which uses compiler version 2.2.2. 
Thanks @Horia Coman for giving hint.

Comment: Does it has to do with file watchers like babel ?